# Executable not found. Dataflow job failing to launch from App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-dataflow

I have an App Engine Flex Python3 service that I've been using to launch my dataflow jobs for years. This past week or so, all of my jobs have started to fail to launch. I didn't even deploy a change, it's as if some change had occurred within App Engine Flex.

This is the error that I am getting:

```
Executable ['/env/bin/python', 'setup.py', 'sdist', '--dist-dir', '/tmp/tmpmeiadu1k'] not found

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/utils/processes.py", line 89, in check_output
    out = subprocess.check_output(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/python3.7/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 411, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "/opt/python3.7/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 488, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "/opt/python3.7/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 800, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/opt/python3.7/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1482, in _execute_child
    restore_signals, start_new_session, preexec_fn)

BlockingIOError: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1523, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1509, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File "/home/vmagent/app/src/utils/decorators.py", line 61, in decorated_function
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vmagent/app/src/handlers/dataflow_task_handlers.py", line 179, in df_day_summary
    wait=False,
  File "/home/vmagent/app/dataflow_tasks/rec_day_summary.py", line 782, in run
    result = p.run()
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 550, in run
    self._options).run(False)
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 574, in run
    return self.runner.run_pipeline(self, self._options)
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/dataflow/dataflow_runner.py", line 475, in run_pipeline
    artifacts = environments.python_sdk_dependencies(options)
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/transforms/environments.py", line 806, in python_sdk_dependencies
    skip_prestaged_dependencies=skip_prestaged_dependencies)
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/portability/stager.py", line 282, in create_job_resources
    setup_options.setup_file, temp_dir, build_setup_args)
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/portability/stager.py", line 775, in _build_setup_package
    processes.check_output(build_setup_args)
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/utils/processes.py", line 91, in check_output
    raise RuntimeError("Executable {} not found".format(args[0]))

RuntimeError: Executable ['/env/bin/python', 'setup.py', 'sdist', '--dist-dir', '/tmp/tmpmeiadu1k'] not found
```

In my pipeline options, i specify `setup_file` to be `./setup.py` which references this file in my project root:

```
import setuptools
    
REQUIRED_PACKAGES = [
   'google-cloud-error-reporting==1.1.2',
   'polyline==1.4.0',
]
setuptools.setup(
    name='dataflow_python_pipeline',
    version='1.0.0',
    description='DataFlow Python Pipeline',
    install_requires=REQUIRED_PACKAGES,
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
)
```

This was originally inspired by this https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-pipeline-dependencies/#multiple-file-dependencies

Comment: Please check the runner (App Engine Flex Python3) has the same Python packages  versions installed as those specified in the `setup.py` file. The packages used in the `setup.py` file are used by Dataflow workers.

Comment: Hmm, my version of google-cloud-logging does differ. I wonder if I'd need to explicitly list all the versions of all the dependencies of those libraries too to make sure pip doesn't pick other ones. So far I tried switching the parameter to `setup_file` to be an absolute path instead of a relative one and it seems to be working. I'll play with the library version next.

Comment: did your workaround work? if it did, please post it as an answer for the community. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Changing my path to my `setup_file` to be an absolute path seemed to fix the issue.

My `setup.py` was sitting in my project root, so the following worked for me:

```
cwd = os.getcwd()
pipeline_options = PipelineOptions.from_dictionary({
    # other pipeline options...
    'setup_file': f'{cwd}/setup.py',
})
```